# Normal map baking acting up

Tags: modeling, baking

How can I fix this? It looks like this picture, revealing a different part of the bake every half second, and after its done it becomes completely solid purple. The bake progress bar fills up slowly, then at about the quarter mark, it jumps to the finish and displays no change in topology.

[image]